# Compiler errors in my program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char push();
char pop();
char display();
char peek();
char reverse();
# define MAX 50
struct stack
    {
        char string[MAX];
        int top= -1;
    };
void main()
    {
        int a;
        printf("Choose an option\n");
        printf("1.Insert\n");
        printf("2.Delete\n");
        printf("3.Display\n");
        printf("4.Peek\n");
        printf("5.Reverse\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
            switch(a)
                {
                    {
                        case 1: push();
                        break;
                    }
                    {
                        case 2: pop();
                    break;
                    }
                    {
                    case 3: display();
                    break;
                    }
                    {
                    case 4: peek();
                    break;
                    }
                    {
                        case 5: reverse();
                    break;
                    }
                    default : printf("Invalid Input");
                }


    }
char push(char a)
    (
        char a;
        printf("Enter the string");
        scanf("%c",&a);
        if(top=MAX-1)
         {
            printf("Stack Overflow");
         }

        else
         (
         top=top+1;
         string[top]=a;
         )

    )

char pop()
    (
        char c;
        (
            if(top=-1)
            {
                printf("Stack Underflow");
            }
            else(
                c=string[top];
                top=top-1;
                printf("The character removed is %c", c);
                )
           )
     )


char display()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0,i<=MAX-1,i++)
            {
                printf("%c", string[i]);
            }
    }


char peek()
    (
     printf("The top element is %c", string[top]);
    )


char reverse()
    (
     int i;
     printf("The reverse of string is");
     for(i=MAX-1,i>=0,i--)

        (
         printf("%c",string[i])
         )

     )
```

This is my program, just started C programming about a month ago.
Following are my errors. Please help. I can't figure out from other answers, if someone can correct my mistake, I will learn better. Thanks

```
prog.c:12:16: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '=' token
         int top= -1;
                ^

prog.c:14:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]
 void main()
      ^

prog.c:54:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'printf'
         printf("Enter the string");
         ^

prog.c:55:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'scanf'
         scanf("%c",&a);
         ^

prog.c:56:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'if'
         if(top=MAX-1)
         ^

prog.c:73:13: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'if'
             if(top=-1)
             ^

prog.c:98:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'printf'
      printf("The top element is %c", string[top]);
      ^

prog.c:96:6: error: 'peek' declared as function returning a function
 char peek()
      ^

prog.c:96:6: error: conflicting types for 'peek'

prog.c:6:6: note: previous declaration of 'peek' was here
 char peek();
      ^

prog.c: In function 'peek':

prog.c:105:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'printf'
      printf("The reverse of string is");
      ^

prog.c:106:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'for'
      for(i=MAX-1,i>=0,i--)
      ^

prog.c:112:6: error: expected '{' at end of input
      )
      ^

prog.c:112:6: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
      )
      ^
```

Comment: You cannot initialize your structs like that in c

Comment: Also `if(top=-1)` is probably a mistake.

Comment: Change `void main` to `int main`. If you are using resources that suggest `void main` then throw them far away and get something written in the last 20 years. If you are in the Indian educational system and still working with TurboC and such obsolete ideas then you have my sympathy but we can't do your homework for you. You must know after a month that you need to deal with your errors by fixing them one by one and recompiling to see which ones remain after each change. If that isn't yet clear to you then start doing it from now.

Comment: Use `{ … }` around the body of a function, not `( … )`.  Amongst others.  Learn to read the error messages; they are usually quite precise (though the 'expected declaration specifiers' one takes a bit of getting used to — it means you've got a serious issue and you've confused the compiler).

Answer (score 2):

`struct stack {...};` defines a type, namely `struct stack`.

You cannot "initialise" a type, nor can you define default values for a `struct` type's members, or what ever your intention is when doing `... top = -1`.

What you could do is define a variable of that type and initialise it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define STRING_MAX (42)

struct Stack {
  char string[STRING_MAX];
  int top;
}


int main(void) {
  struct Stack stack = {
    "top entry",
    1
  };

  printf("string = '%s', top = %d\n", stack.string, stack.top);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The example above prints:

```
string = 'top entry', top = 1
```